# Woocommerce get next / previous product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to find a way to add two links to each product page in woocommerce

One link to send the user to next product and one to previous product, but I can not figure out a way to make this happen. Has anyone done this or knows how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After doing some more research the following simple solution solved the problem:

```
<?php previous_post_link('&laquo; %link'); ?>  previous product    
<?php next_post_link('%link &raquo;'); ?>      next product
```

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that next/previous products can be limited to those having the same terms as the current product.
`<?php previous_post_link( 'Previous: %link', '%title', true, '', 'product_cat' ); ?>`