# WordPress previous_post_link with multiple custom taxonomies

Tags: php, wordpress, navigation

I am using previous_post_link and next_post_link to navigate between posts in the same custom taxonomy. The problem I am having is that I need to navigate between posts that have the same two custom taxonomies.

For example on a product page I would like to go to the next product that was the same type and brand. Nike and T-shirt for example.

Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Woocommerce get next / previous product SAME category](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15977615/woocommerce-get-next-previous-product-same-category)

Comment: I am not using woocommerce, I have just used the above example to help explain what I am trying to do.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask -- "Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example."

Comment: as christina mentioned, post relevent code.

Comment: Hi This is the code I am using at the moment but it is obviously just using one of the custom taxonomies <?php previous_post_link( '%link', 'Previous Rug', TRUE, ' ', 'collection' ); ?>

Comment: Are you using this function inside the loop?

Comment: Hi @Paul I am, the function above is working as it should but its not what I need it to do.

Comment: Sorry I misread the question, it would definitely need some custom code alright. Nike and T-Shirt are 2 different taxonomies like Brand and Product Type or something like that? So the next link would go specifically to the next Nike T-Shirt.

Comment: Hi @Paul . That is correct, so at the moment I can only get it to work for one of the taxonomies, either next Nike product or next T-Shirt for example but not both combined.