# How to hide previous / next links on product pages in WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, navigation

I have seen several users discussing this issue around the web, but no question exists yet on StackOverflow. How exactly would you hide the previous / next links on a WooCommerce product?

Better yet, is there a solution that is theme-agnostic, as most solutions are theme-specific.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13597687/woocommerce-get-next-previous-product

Comment: You can use either javascript, or css, or php or a combination of these three langauges.

Comment: Or you might be able to use this: https://www.8theme.com/topic/remove-the-next-previous-product-links-on-the-side-of-single-product-page/ although this seems theme-dependent.

Comment: It depends on the theme… For example on Storefront theme, you will use this CSS rule: `.storefront-product-pagination{display:none;}` or/and this jQuery script line: `jQuery('.storefront-product-pagination').remove();`…